# How do I only allow certain functions to work on a specific Discord server ID?

Tags: discord.js

I have a joke Discord bot which automatically nicknames people for the main server it's on, but I also allow some other friends to put it on their server for fun. The only issue is, the automatic rename thing also happens there.

What would the correct line of code be to make it so the lines of code responsible for the auto-nickname feature only run when someone joins a specific server and not any server with the bot?

Answer (score 0):

Each guild in discord has a guild ID, witch is unique, so you could use it to determine if the bot should do the nickname change in that specific guild.

I can't show you an exact line of code since you didn't specify the language you are writing your bot in but I'll write the basic idea of it.

```
if (message.guild.id != "Your main guild id") return;
```

This assumes that you execute this on a per message basis, but since you didn't provide much more detail this is as much as I can give in terms of code example.

Another thing to consider is how to get the guild ID in the first place, firstly enable development mode in discord in case you haven't already, to do that you should:

1. Open your Discord settings
2. click on Appearance
3. Scroll down to Developer mode and enable it.

Once you did that, you can right click the server name and go to "Copy ID", and you have your id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, I put, "Discord.js" as at tag, which indicates JavaScript.